# Grub v2: kernel "has invalid signature"

Tags: grub2

Can somebody explain what this exact error message means?

```
grub> linuxefi /boot/i386/loader/linux
error: /boot/i386/loader/linux has invalid signature.
```

What is Grub trying to tell me? That the file isn't a valid ELF binary? Or that it isn't 64-bit? Or something else?

(This is Grub v2.00, not Grub Legacy.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trying to say that it can't verify your kernel image signature. Each vendor signs kernel by own key. Grub2 installed by vendor normally knows only keys of this vendor, so it cannot verify file signed by other vendor.

Comment: Oh dear. This suggests that the OpenSUSE 32-bit kernel isn't signed by OpenSUSE. Damn...