# Grub-EFI: disable signature check?

Tags: grub2, uefi

Following on from [my previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124065/grub-v2-kernel-has-invalid-signature), it seems that Grub-EFI refuses to boot any kernel which isn't signed. Which is a problem, because the kernel I want to boot isn't signed. So what I'm wondering is... Is there any configuration option to switch this check off?

Comment: Is it solved ? How ?

Answer (score 4):

*If* you can drop to a shell, you can set a grub environment variable, as stated in grub.info:

> Note that signature checking does *not* prevent an attacker with
>   (serial, physical, ...)  console access from dropping manually to the
>   GRUB console and executing:
>
> ```
>  set check_signatures=no
> ```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work with Rocky 8.6's grub at this point in time

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can disable this via the system's BIOS. Per the instructions in this article titled: [Managing EFI Boot Loaders for Linux: Dealing with Secure Boot](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html).

*excerpt*

> #### Disabling Secure Boot
>
> If you aren't convinced that Secure Boot will improve your system's security, you might want to disable the feature entirely. Given the fact that most malware targets Windows, this approach is most reasonable on computers that don't run Windows. You'll have to be comfortable navigating your firmware's setup screens to do this. Unfortunately, there's no standardization in where Secure Boot options might be located or what they might be called; therefore, I can't provide a procedure that will work for every computer. I can, however, describe the options on one computer I own that supports Secure Boot: The ASUS P8H77-I motherboard. This board ships with Secure Boot options disabled, but based on my experimentation, I can see how it would probably ship if it were used on a computer with Windows 8 pre-installed. Based on those assumptions, to disable Secure Boot, you should:
>
> 1. Enter the computer's firmware utility by pressing Del during the initial stages of the boot process (before any boot loader appears). Some computers use other keys for this purpose; examine your early boot-time messages or read your computer's manual to learn what to use.
> 2. If you're configured to boot in EZ Mode, press F7 to enter Advanced Mode.
> 3. Click the Boot tab.
> 4. Click Security Boot Parameters near the bottom-left of the screen. (It's conceivable you'll need to scroll down to see this on some systems.)
> 5. Change OS Type from Windows 8 UEFI to Other Legacy & UEFI. The Secure Boot Mode and Key Management options should disappear.
> 6. Press the F10 key to save your changes and reboot the computer.

#### References

- [Ubuntu Official Documentation - UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)
- [Fedora - UEFI Secure Boot Guide Edition 18.4](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html-single/UEFI_Secure_Boot_Guide/index.html)

Comment: I know that I can ask _the firmware_ to not check the signature on _GRUB_. My question is, can I ask _GRUB_ to not check the signature on _the Linux Kernel_?

Comment: GRUB seemingly checks for signatures even if secure boot is off in some situations so this answer is not relevant.